# Ошибка при установке Docker на Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, windows-server

При установке `Docker` на `Windows Server 2019` постоянно вылазит одна и та же ошибка. В чем может быть проблема?

Попробовал версию 2.5.0.1
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3.1.0

```
Docker Desktop 3.1.0
Installation failed

Component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction failed: Failed to start service: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно
   в CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   в CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

3.2.0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я пробовал решить проблему по советам из [этой ветки на гите](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/6091), но мне не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему не удалось решить с дистрибутивом, но получилось установить через `PowerShell`

`Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force`

Из документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server